# Chromatic polynomial by contraction deletion

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Consider the graph $G$ with $5$ vertices labelled $1,\cdots,5$ with edges $(12)$,$(13)$, $(23)$, $(34)$ and $(45)$ which means we have a triangle $(123)$ and two other edges $(34)$ and $(45)$. I want to apply the contraction deletion propety to this graph by taking the edge $e=(13)$ $$P(G,k)=P(G-e,k)-P(G/e,k)$$
Now $G-e$ is just a tree on $5$ vertices so $P(G-e,k)=k(k-1)^4$ and $G/e$ is a tree on $4$ vertices so $P(G/e,k)=k(k-1)^3$ so $P(G,k)=k(k-1)^4-k(k-1)^3=k(k-1)^3(k-2)$
but I read on a paper that $P(G,k)=k^2(k-1)(k-2)$ and I don't know what I did wrong!

the computations are here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.04320.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation is correct and $P(G,k) = k(k-1)^3(k-2)$.

The paper is wrong about the chromatic polynomials of the graphs in Figure 1, on all three counts; probably the text reflects an older version of the diagrams. (For example, if you remove the bottom vertex from all three graphs, then the resulting graphs have the chromatic polynomials that the paper claims they do.)

We know that $k^2(k-1)(k-2)$ can't *possibly* be the chromatic polynomial of this graph, because the chromatic polynomial of an $n$-vertex graph is a degree-$n$ polynomial.